# How to extract color from a 3rd party SolidColorBrush resource

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation, coloranimation, solidcolorbrush

I have a DynamicResource called "resource" defined by a 3rd party. It references a SolidColorBrush and its color changes based on certain things.

I need to create a color animation that starts with the current color of "resource" but I don't know how to extract the Color from the resource in xaml and use it in the ColorAnimation.

Is this somehow possible without using code behind?

Comment: Is it really necessary to lookup the resource as DynamicResource? You might try to access it as StaticResource and then simply use that for the Source of a binding.

Comment: @Clemens: yes it is because its value changes based on some logic defined by the 3rd party as well :S